# Choosing correct tense and article

Tags: tense, articles, past-tense, present-perfect

Which one is correct?

1. I just **sent** them **an** email
2. I just **have sent** them **an** email
3. I just **sent** them **the** email
4. I just **have sent** them **the** email

Suppose I need to say this to my colleague, *who is also in recipients list in this email?*
 I'm clarifying this because as I think this should lead me to conclusion that email is pretty concrete thing and  as my colleague probably knows what I'm talking about I should use **the**... (but on intuitive level I'm not sure)

Comment: #2 and #4 are "unnatural" (we nearly always put adverbial ***just*** in between the auxiliary and the main verb, as ***I have just sent***). But this is completely unrelated to the matter of whether to use a definite or indefinite article (if you're "not sure", and the best you can say is your colleague "probably" knows what email you're referring to, that's not really enough to justify ***the** email*). And none of ***that*** is relevant to the matter of whether to use Simple Past or Present Perfect.

Comment: Sure, these are two separate questions - about correct tense and article.

Comment: You are only supposed to ask about ***one thing*** in one question. Asking multiple questions at once makes the post Off Topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have spoken to your colleague about this email, or if your colleague is expecting this email as a recipient, I would just say:

> I have just sent the email.

Since your colleague is one of the recipients, it may be awkward to say "I have just sent ***them*** the email." However, if your main intention is to send ***them*** this email, and you just want to confirm it with your colleague, you may also say:

> I have just sent them the email.

If you look at this link from the [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/just-yet-still-and-already), you will see that

> Just used with the present perfect means 'a short time before'.

and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/just) says:

> We often use the present perfect or past perfect with this meaning of just when we refer to a short time before the moment of speaking.

However, more and more commonly, you will find "just" used with Past Tense Simple. In your conversation with your colleague, it is definitely ok to tell him

> I just sent them the email.

However, in more formal situations or written contexts, I'd stick to Present Perfect.

Comment: Thank you. So you choose Present Perfect. I wonder, what degree of misunderstanding or awkwardness this may bring if I use Past Simple?
As for "them" usage, that's because actually email is going to third-party and I just added my colleague to "copy" list, to make him aware of this.

Comment: You can use Past Tense, it would not be wrong.  Will edit and explain.